# onclick open hidden selectbox options on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

When I press on a link I want to open the selectbox options. On mobile phones options are popping out.

I tried with `.click()`, `.trigger("click")`, `.change()` nothing seems to open it. Is this even possible?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#filters a', function(e) {
  $('select').trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="filters">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Open selectbox 1</a>
    <div style="display:none">
      <select multiple>
        <option>option 1</option>
        <option>option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you asking if this is possible on a desktop PC? If so, then the answer is no.

Comment: I have specified, on mobile phones, ios android

Comment: That's why I asked - your question implies it's already working there: `On mobile phones options are popping out`. However I would assume the answer is still a 'no, you can't do this'.

Comment: fixed with opacity: 0 and position absolute, select stays on top of text. thanks

Comment: So the problem was instead making the element visible, not showing its options. Please describe your goals more clearly in future questions.